# How do I read special characters in a file using a .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I have a .bat file(batch file) and I want it to be able to read a file, but it has lots of special characters the code I currently have is`type "C:\Users\mehid\Desktop\Command prompt game\Stuff for coders ;)\Map.txt"` and the .txt file has `─ │ ┌ ┐ └ ┘ ├ ┤ ┬ ┴ ┼` and those types of characters it outputs this `ΓöÇ Γöé Γöî ΓöÉ Γöö Γöÿ Γö£ Γöñ Γö¼ Γö┤ Γö╝`

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for your issue, is that your `Map.txt` file was saved with UTF8 encoding, and your batch file has not told cmd.exe to use anything other than the default codepage.

The simplest way to change that, other than changing the encoding of your text file, is to change your codepage to something which can read UTF8 characters, i.e. codepage 65001.

Example:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Rem Determining, and saving to a variable, your current codepage.
Set "codepage=" & For /F "Tokens=*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com'
) Do For %%H In (%%G) Do If Not %%~nH Equ 65001 (Set "codepage=%%~nH"
    %SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com 65001 1> NUL)

Echo typing your text file using codepage 65001 & Echo(
Type "C:\Users\mehid\Desktop\Command prompt game\Stuff for coders ;)\Map.txt"
Pause

Rem Changing your codepage back to what it was previously.
If Defined codepage %SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com %codepage% 1> NUL

Echo typing your text file using your original codepage, [%codepage%]. & Echo(
Type "C:\Users\mehid\Desktop\Command prompt game\Stuff for coders ;)\Map.txt"
Pause
```

Comment: It works kinda, but it keep replacing a few things with questions mark blocks

Comment: Well, as you've provided absolutely no information about the encoding of the file, your current codepage, what OS you're using, what font your cmd.exe is using, I'm not quite sure what else you were expecting. On top of that, codepage 65001 doesn't read all unicode characters, so if you want more you should ensure that your text files are using characters which your intended viewer can recognize. For the ones you provided it worked absolutely perfectly in the test I just ran, was I supposed to guess which other ones you were using and assume all of the above information?

Comment: Ill just try to figure out why, its only a few of this character and its always the same ones also I'm using windows and I am only using the ones I showed, some of the ─ show as a question mark thingy
┌─────────────────┐
└─────────────────┘
this is the part of the file I am having trouble with, it show as this here, but it shows as
┌───────────��─────┐
└─────────────────┘
instead

Answer (score 0):

I removed some characters at the beginning of the file that weren't needed and it fixed itself